# Mysql DATE_FORMAT sorting is not working

Tags: mysql, cakephp

I am working in cakephp framework,

In that I am storing date string in varchar field. I need to convert it timezone after that need to change the format. here is the query.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(cast( CONVERT_TZ(`leads`.`221`,
                        'UTC',
                        'America/Los_Angeles') as datetime), '%b %d %Y %h:%i %p') 
from leads order by DATE_FORMAT(cast( CONVERT_TZ(`leads`.`221`,
                        'UTC',
                        'America/Los_Angeles') as datetime), '%b %d %Y %h:%i %p') desc.
```

Here timezone covert, date format everything working fine. but while sorting this field it works like alphabetical ordering not like date ordering.

I know we need to remove extra mysql functions from order by field. then only it works when we give like

```
 `order by `leads`.`221` desc`
```

But I cannot able to give like this. because it is created by cakephp framework. I cannot able override.

Please give a solution.

Comment: Try converting string to date first like this "SELECT DATE_FORMAT(STR_TO_DATE('01/12/2013', '%d/%m/%Y'), '%Y%m');"
If you give me some sample data of leads column, will definitely give you proper solution to this.

Answer (score 0):

Using AS in your query will let you order by the operation you are doing.

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(cast( CONVERT_TZ(`leads`.`221`,
                    'UTC',
                    'America/Los_Angeles') as datetime), '%b %d %Y %h:%i %p') 
as `new_date` from `leads` order by `new_date` DESC;
```